# Why does Netbeans ask for Master Password at the begining?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans

Upon switching to ubuntu, one of the differences I noticed was on netbeans. It asks for master password an every startup. I am wondering, why is this so? And why do I have to keep on doing this on every startup.

> #### Additional Details:
>
> System:      Ubuntu Studio 12.04
>
> Netbeans Version: Netbeans 7.1

Comment: How did you install Netbeans? Which version of Netbeans? (That's some interesting transparency in your screenshot)

Comment: It's explained pretty well [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMasterPasswordDialog).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I do have gnome keyring, and it still asks for master password.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs because Netbeans looks for "libgnome-keyring.so" file, which exists in your system as "libgnome-keyring.so.**0**"

#### 1st solution (preferred)

Create a link file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so" linking to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0"

```
$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ sudo ln -s libgnome-keyring.so.0 libgnome-keyring.so
```

#### 2nd solution

Install libgmone-keyring-dev package and problem should be fixed

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev
```

The installation of these package creates this link file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so" linking to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0"

Answer (score 1):

The solution appeared to be simple. A missing package was preventing Netbeans from using Gnome Keyring.

So install libgnome-keyring-dev

`sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev`